# How does one configure synergy to use multiple X11 screens (:0, :1, ...)?

Tags: kvm

Configuring synergy for multiple computers, each with a single screen, is fairly easy.  But it is not so obvious how to configure multiple X11 screens.  For example, sys1, a minimac is on the right. sys1 is the server and has a single monitor (screen).  To the left of sys1 is a Fedora 9 system, sys2, with two X11 displays: sys2:0.0 and sys2:0.1  I'm guessing that one invents names and uses aliases with ports specified (5900 and 5901 in my case), which is the avenue I will investigate.  But surely someone has crossed this bridge before.

Comment: Truly, a brilliant answer! :-)

Comment: it makes your life easier if you're using Xinerama in your X11 configuration.. that also simplifies the synergy configuration.

Answer (score 4):

I found the basic answer [here](http://www.gentoo.org/news/en/gwn/20070910-newsletter.xml).  Here is the config file for this example:

```
section: screens
  sys1
  sys2
  sys21
end

section: links
  sys1:
    left = sys21
  sys2:
    left = sys2
    right = sys1
  sys21:
    right = sys21
end
```

is basically all you need.  Then, start the synergy programs as follows:

On the server (sys1):

```
$ synergys -f --config synergy.conf --name sys1
```

On the client, display :0.0

```
$ synergyc -f -n sys2 sys1
```

On the client, display :0.1

```
$ synergyc -f -n sys21 sys1
```

And away you go ...

Comment: The link is gone. Going the other direction ( mac client to linux server ) I'm trying to get a display specified but having trouble.